# Riley Riddle: Your mother wouldn't approve

Tags: riddle, wordplay

<sub>I wanted to try my hand at one of these since it seems to be so popular.</sub>

> My prefix is what leeches do.
>   To get my infix, do the following:
>   Take what you are doing right now, and turn it sideways.
>   My suffix is how people get around.
>   I can be an excuse for infidelity.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm thinking its

> succubus

My prefix is what leeches do.

> Suck

To get my infix, do the following:
Take what you are doing right now, and turn it sideways.

> User 1848 got this below in the comments while I was stumped - right now you see this riddle (accounting for POV shifts anyway). "you see" = UC, which is then "turned" to CU, which is indeed the missing segment i needed.

My suffix is how people get around.

> Bus

I can be an excuse for infidelity

> Well, I dont think "a sex demon made me do it" will fly as an excuse, but feel free to try...

Comment: That was quick. You're right. But I'd like to see you get the infix. P.S. it's heavy on wordplay.

Comment: Also, it may be easier to work backward for the infix.

Comment: I'd like to see me get the infix too! I'm currently thinking rot13[bzrguvat gb qb jvgu phorf (r.t. gur zngurzngvpny bcrengvba) ] - am I tepid, or freezing?

Comment: Maybe currently 'you see' and 'uc' turned sideways is 'cu,' which makes up the middle portion of the word?

Comment: @1848 - oh thats terrible! that must be it!

Comment: @1848 Yes, yes it is. It's a heavy play on words.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know wouldn't uc turned sideways be cn?

Comment: @thecoder Actually, originally I was only thinking of the u for the infix rot13(fhp-h-ohf), the extra c just happened to work like that too.